# Client side validation doesn't work for the dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.InsertCustomer.CountryID, Model.lstCountry, new { @class = "DropDownListFor" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m =>m.InsertCustomer.CountryID)
```

View Model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select Country")]
public string CountryID { get; set; }
```

Method to create a list for the dropdown

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getCountry()
{
     DNC_DAL.clsCustomerMaster _objDalUser = new DNC_DAL.clsCustomerMaster();
     DataTable dtCountry = new DataTable();
     dtCountry = _objDalUser.GetCountry();
     List<SelectListItem> lstCountry = new List<SelectListItem>();
     SelectListItem firstOption = new SelectListItem() { Text = "---Select One---" };
     lstCountry.Add(firstOption);


     foreach (DataRow drCountry in dtCountry.Rows)
     {
         SelectListItem Country = new SelectListItem() { Text = drCountry["DCM_DESC"].ToString(), Value = drCountry["DCM_ID"].ToString() };
         lstCountry.Add(Country);
     }

     return lstCountry;
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult wfrmCustomerMaster()
{
     Models.clsCustomerMaster CustomerModel = new Models.clsCustomerMaster();
     IEnumerable<SelectListItem> strCountry = null;
     strCountry = CustomerModel.getCountry();
     CustomerModel.lstCountry = strCountry;

     return View(CustomerModel);
}
```

All the other validations( Not posted in the question) work perfectly on the page except for the dropdown validation, I wonder why?

Comment: Delete `lstCountry.Add(firstOption);` from your code and use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.InsertCustomer.CountryID, Model.lstCountry, "---Select One---", new { @class = "DropDownListFor" })` so you correctly generate a label option with a null value

Comment: check what's in your `firstOption` object. If `Value = 0`, then it's normal for validator

Comment: thanks both of you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is adding the first option as

```
<option>---Select One---</option>
```

which does not have a `value=""` attribute, which means if you select it, the value of the `<select>` element will be `"---Select One---"`, which is valid (i.e. its not `null` or an empty `string`).

Instead, to generate a label option with a `null` value, use the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%7D,System.String,System.Object%29) that accepts a `optionLabel`, which will generate the first option as

```
<option value="">---Select One---</option>
```

and remove the code in the `getCountry()` which generates this option